# Converting a single record with a start and end date into multiple records in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, looker-studio

I have a table with with 3 columns, "start date", "end date" and "amount". I want to create multiple records split by day in a new table as per below.

This table is a source for a Data Studio report and so ideally I would want it to update automatically if possible.

Original Table

```
Start Date  End Date    Amount
01/01/2020  05/01/2020  55
02/01/2020  04/01/2020  90
```

New Table

```
Date    Amount
01/01/2020  55
02/01/2020  55
03/01/2020  55
04/01/2020  55
05/01/2020  55
02/01/2020  90
03/01/2020  90
04/01/2020  90
```

Comment: Did either of the answers give you a solution you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used google-apps-scripts to get your Original table and get the New table in the same google sheet. You may change this code according to your requirement. Hope this helps!

Assuming you are new to app scripts, I will explain from basics.

Open your google sheets document and then go to Tools -> Script editor. You will directed to scripts.google.com and will get a blank apps script file(.cs extension). Use this script to get the following output. Run the code and allow permission to the google sheet. Hope this helped! do ask if you need further clarifications!

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date_values = []
  var amount
  date1 = data[1][0]
  date2 = data[1][1]
  amount = data[1][2]
  while(date1<=date2){
    date_values.push(new Date(date1))
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate()+1)
  }
  doTest(date_values, amount)
}

function doTest(arr, amount) {
  const no_dates = arr.length
  for (var k=2; k<no_dates+2; k++){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E'+k).setValue(arr.shift());
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F'+k).setValue(amount);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at posting here, but I think I found a formula way to achieve what you want.  It does require a helper column though, although someone may know how to eliminate that requirement.

Assuming your data is in B3:D6, the two main formula are, in F3:

```
=ArrayFormula(rept(B3:B6 & ";",(C3:C6-B3:B6+1)))
```

and in F10:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate( F3:F6,";"),";",1,1)))
```

Here is a sample table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y4sH9oDdO1TiC3i-sfZJDZGGmEr9PIZd6k-da5f6P2c/edit?usp=sharing

The first does a date subtraction, and repeats the "start date" value as many times as needed, with a separator.  The second concatenates all the date values from the helper column, then splits all of them into one column.

Lastly, a VLOOKUP is done using the date values against the original data column, to find the amount.

There may be limits on the CONCATENATE function (50,000 char?) that limit the maximum number of values, depending on how large your date differences are.

Let me know if this helps at all.